# Adding a route via a different subnet on linux

Tags: linux, routing

Here's my configuration :

> IP adress : **192.168.1.4** Netmask : **255.255.255.0** Default gw :
>   **192.168.1.200**

Routing table :

```
    Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.168.2.1     192.168.1.254   255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 venet0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 venet0
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.200   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 venet0
```

When I try to add a route via the subnet 192.168.2.0, I get the following **RTNETLINK answers: No such process**
Example :

```
#ip route add 8.8.8.8/32 via 192.168.2.1 dev venet0:0
#RTNETLINK answers: No such process
```

Is there a way to accomplish this kind of thing ?

And one more question : I'd like to be able to forward all my incoming trafic to the gateway at 192.168.2.1 ... How Can I do this ? This doesn't work of course :

```
#ip route add default via 192.168.2.1
#RTNETLINK answers: No such process
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Source-based routing has been deprecated manymany years ago.

Some routers accept such a statement (called indirect next-hop), but locally (at your 192.168.1.4) it would result in this - and that's all you can do:

```
#ip route add 8.8.8.8/32 via 192.168.1.254 dev venet0:0
```

Anything behind 192.168.1.254 lies only in the responsibility of 192.168.1.254. Do you have access to this device?

To the second question - I do not understand, what you want to do...

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
For the second question, what I'd like to do is a backup gateway in case of the main one is failing (which is often)... I know that 192.168.2.1 would route my trafic to the Internet, but the only link I have is 192.168.1.254 which is a "bridge" between our two subnets. And no, I don't have access to this device :(
P.S : Oops there was a typo in my second question, I've just edited the IP address